# How can we Sum the data of .csv file columnwise using d3.js

Tags: d3.js

Given this .csv file:

```
date,jan,feb,march
1-1-2011,1,2,3  
1-2-2011,2,3,4  
1-3-2011,1,4,5
```

and I want an array that contains value like: [4,9,12].

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 3):

Even though thatOneGuy's answer is perfect, this is way shorter:

```
d3.csv("yourFile.csv", function(data){

    var totalSum = [d3.sum(data.map(function(d){ return d.jan})),
       d3.sum(data.map(function(d){ return d.feb})),
       d3.sum(data.map(function(d){ return d.march}))];

    console.log(totalSum);//[4, 9, 12]

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work :

```
d3.csv('linktocsvfilehere.csv',function(data){

var sumArray = [];
var janArray= [], febArray= [], marchArray = [];

data.forEach(function(d){
   janArray.push(d.jan); //push all jan values into jan array
   febArray.push(d.feb); //push all feb values into feb array
   marchArray.push(d.march); //push all march values into march array
});

var janSum = getSumOfArray(janArray); //get sum of jan array
var febSum = getSumOfArray(febArray);
var marchSum = getSumOfArray(marchArray);

sumArray.push(janSum,febSum,marchSum);

console.log(sumArray); //here is your array you want

function getSumOfArray(array){

   var thisSum = 0;

   for(var i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
      thisSum += array[i];
   }
   return thisSum;
}
})
```

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I believe you did, less code is always better (if it gives the correct output that is ;) )